# Using BLE module by blueradios

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, at-commands

I want to use the bluradios BLE module. [Here](http://www.blueradios.com/BR-LE4.0-S2.pdf) is what I am talking about,

[Another link](http://www.blueradios.com/hardware_LE4.0-S2.htm) for the material available on the site.

Now, I would like to use AT command set to program the module. The site says that there are AT command sets available, but I do not see them on the site.
I am a rookie, so I would prefer using the AT command set, can you tell me what all I need to buy to get this going?
Last time I used rn-42 bluetooth module, and to program that, all I had to do was send AT commands over serial via arduino, Can I do the same with the blueradios module?

Answer (score 1):

in  [https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/RF/BlueRadios_ATMP_Commands_Rev_3.5.2.1.4.0.pdf][1]

You might be refer the following sentences.
First your arduino boards' UART TX/RX/GND pin to BlueRadio's RX/TX/GND connect.
and you programming the arduino board uart to 9600 baud, 8bit,N (no parity)

It's HW setup. also, You can first setup your BlueRadio module with PC UART.

---

> Blockquote

Embedded testing:
For the DB9 (RS-232) connector, connect the TX(2), RX(3) and GND(5) to the embedded computer or micro
controller. If you are not using hardware flow control, connect RTS(7) to CTS(8) on the DB-9 connector. When
connecting the TX and RX from the DB9 connector, you cannot connect/short the CTS and RTS at terminal J4
these are two different circuits.

> Blockquote

And in your arduino or in your PC Serial program,

```
    UART.send("ATFRST\r\n");
    // and wait "OK" or "ERR"
    UART.recv(buf);
    if (strstr(buf, "OK") )
    { 
         // ok factory reset
    }
```

do like this way , you refer the following document's AT command lists.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find [this](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/RF/BlueRadios_ATMP_Commands_Rev_3.5.2.1.4.0.pdf).

Their website seems to imply that they want you to email them directly or join the forum to get this information.

Comment: You should add some of the information here. When the link dies your answer becomes useless.